# How to override spring Environment variables programmatically

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using a bootstrap.properties file in my spring boot application. Is it possible to override the value of the property defined in bootstrap.properties through code.

I understand we can override the properties by passing value as a runtime argument while running the application.

Tried to set the variable value through System.setProperty() method.

The org.springframework.core.env.Environment does not have any methods to set the properties. Is there a way to add new property or override an existing property in spring core Environment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. All the current implementation of `Environment` is also a `ConfigurableEnvironment` which allows you to get its internal `MutablePropertySources`. After getting  `MutablePropertySources`, you can use it to configure any searching precedence of any property .

For example , to set your own properties that always has the highest precedence , you can do :

```
if(environment instanceof ConfigurableEnvironment) {
        ConfigurableEnvironment env = (ConfigurableEnvironment)environment;

        Map<String,Object> prop = new HashMap<>();
        prop.put("foo", "fooValue");
        prop.put("bar", "barValue");

        MutablePropertySources mps = env.getPropertySources();
        mps.addFirst(new MapPropertySource("MyProperties", prop)); 

}
```

Then `environment.getProperty("foo")` should return `fooValue`.

Comment: Thanks @Ken Chan ! I was trying to override encrypt.key property in bootstrap.properties for encryption/decryption. Map<String, Object> prop = new HashMap<>();
    prop.put("encrypt.key", "abcdef");

    MutablePropertySources mps = env.getPropertySources();
    mps.addFirst(new OriginTrackedMapPropertySource("applicationConfig: [classpath:/bootstrap.properties]", prop));. But however, for encryption, the key defined in bootstrap.properties is being used, not the overridden property.